# When should the label element be used?

Tags: html

I was learning some HTML and I got confused about use of the `label` element because I found it in many places, with inputs in a form, with `optgroup` tag for the sections in a `select` element, before the `textarea` elelemt, etc.

So, is there a rule when to use it and when to avoid using it in the wrong way? especially in HTML5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<label>` element should be used with form fields: most types of `<input>`, `<select>` and `<textarea>`. If has a `for` attribute that holds the `id` of the related element. So, if you click the label, the related element is focused.

#### [Example Usage at Jsbin](http://jsbin.com/upexIC/1/edit?html,output)

```
<label for="textinput">Enter data here</label>
<input id="textinput>"

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<label for="checkbox">What this box does</label>

<input type="radio" id="radio_opt1" name="radiogroup">
<label for="radio_opt1">Option description</label>
<input type="radio" id="radio_opt2" name="radiogroup">
<label for="radio_opt2">Option description</label>

<label for="select">Select an option</label>
<select id="select">
    <option>Some option</option>
</select>

<label for="textarea">Enter data into the textarea</label>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
```

In `<optgroup>` elements, there is a `label` attribute, which is not the same as the label elements, although its function is similar: identifying a certain group of options:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="First group">
        <option>Some option</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="First group">
        <option>Some option</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Comment: So, no labels outside forms?

Comment: Actually I believe they're not invalid outside forms, but were created with form fields in mind. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element.

Comment: `Label` elements are to be associated with *controls* such as `input` and `select`. Controls are most often used inside forms, as form fields, but thet may appear outside forms, too, either because they are associated with forms via a `form` attribute (HTML5) or, more often, since they have functionality implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Thanks for the accurate definition. Note that a single label element, unrelated to any control, inside the body, doesn't make the HTML invalid (the w3c validator lets it pass).

Answer (score 1):

> **Label**: This attribute explicitly associates the label being defined with another control.

So the `label` attribute should use when you want to show some text or label for another controls like textbox, checkbox etc.

And the important thing is

> When present, the value of this attribute must be the same as the value of the id attribute of some other control in the same document. When absent, the label being defined is associated with the element's contents.

[Look at here for the documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1)

Comment: so it is only used with form controls? no with other elements outside the form, right?

Comment: No, you can use it outside of the form as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not HTML5 exclusive:)

Label could be used in connection with form element such as `<input>, <select>, <textarea>`. Clicking on label would automatically change focus to connected element.

There are two ways connecting label with element:

1. Put element inside label
2. Add `for` attribute for label, where `for` value is `id` of element need to be connected

Example (taken from http://htmlbook.ru/html/label):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>LABEL</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="handler.php">
   <p><b>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</b></p>
   <p><input type="checkbox" id="check1"><label for="check1">Lorem</label><Br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="check2"><label for="check2">Ipsum</label><Br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="check3"><label for="check3">Dolor</label><Br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="check4"><label for="check4">Sit amet</label></p>
  </form> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be used in forms with other elements **only**. It can be before, after, or around existing form control.
Here's an example by [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_label.asp).

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="male" value="male"><br>
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="sex" id="female" value="female"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```